# WMI TerminalServices __SystemSecurity.GetSecurityDescriptor() Unexpected Error

Tags: windows, wmi-query, wmic

**Summary**: Execution of WMI Method against remote server returns "Unexpected Error". Command returns expected results when executed locally on either server (Server1 against Server1, Server2 against Server2) but returns "Unexpected Error" when running against any remote server (Server1 vs Server2 or Server2 against Server1).

**Outlier**: When executing method against any other namespace, the command executes without error.

**Environment**: Two 2008R2 servers, in the same subnet, on the same domain, with equal (managed) patching levels; Commands run by domain user in admin group on each server; There are no firewall, software or otherwise *known* rules that would inhibit inter-server traffic.

**Command**: `WMIC.EXE /NODE:"SERVER2" /AUTHLEVEL:Pktprivacy /NAMESPACE:\\ROOT\CIMV2\TERMINALSERVICES Class __SystemSecurity Call GetSecurityDescriptor`

**Executed Locally** (From SERVER1 to SERVER1) **Success**:

`d:\>WMIC.EXE /NODE:"SERVER1" /AUTHLEVEL:Pktprivacy /NAMESPACE:\\ROOT\CIMV2\TERMINALSERVICES Class __SystemSecurity call GetSecurityDescriptor
Executing (__SystemSecurity)->GetSecurityDescriptor()
Method execution successful.
Out Parameters:
...`

**Executed against remote Server** (Server1 to Server2) **ERROR**:

`d:\>WMIC.EXE /NODE:"SERVER2" /AUTHLEVEL:Pktprivacy /NAMESPACE:\\ROOT\CIMV2\TERMINALSERVICES Class __System
Security call GetSecurityDescriptor
Executing (__SystemSecurity)->GetSecurityDescriptor()
ERROR:
Description = Unexpected error`

**Executed to alternate Namespace** (Server1 to Server2) **Success**:

`d:\>WMIC.EXE /NODE:"SERVER2" /AUTHLEVEL:Pktprivacy /NAMESPACE:\\ROOT\CIMV2\SECURITY\MICROSOFTTPM Class __SystemSecurity call GetSecurityDescriptor
Executing (__SystemSecurity)->GetSecurityDescriptor()
Method execution successful.
Out Parameters:
...`

**Debugging Steps** (WMIDiag.vbs v2.1): There was nothing in the log that indicated additional issues with the ROOT\CIMV2\TERMINALSERVICES namespace, however it did specifically identify the namespace as requiring PACKET PRIVACY (AUTHENTICATION level 6), which *does allow for the query of the class but not execution of the method.*

`73751 09:28:50 (0) ** INFO: WMI namespace(s) requiring PACKET PRIVACY: .................................................................... 4 NAMESPACE(S)!
73752 09:28:50 (0) ** - ROOT/CIMV2/SECURITY/MICROSOFTTPM.
73753 09:28:50 (0) ** - ROOT/CIMV2/TERMINALSERVICES.
73754 09:28:50 (0) ** - ROOT/WEBADMINISTRATION.
73755 09:28:50 (0) ** - ROOT/SERVICEMODEL.
73756 09:28:50 (0) ** => When remotely connecting, the namespace(s) listed require(s) the WMI client to
73757 09:28:50 (0) **    use an encrypted connection by specifying the PACKET PRIVACY authentication level.
73758 09:28:50 (0) **    (RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_PRIVACY or PktPrivacy flags)
73759 09:28:50 (0) **    i.e. 'WMIC.EXE /NODE:"SERVER2" /AUTHLEVEL:Pktprivacy /NAMESPACE:\\ROOT\SERVICEMODEL Class __SystemSecurity'`

**Plea for help:** Suggestions for further debugging this issue or alterations to the command that would allow successful remote execution of the method.

Comment: even i am facing the same issue but only when server is Windows 2008 R2. Remote from Windows 2008 R2 -> Windows 2008 works fine.